# Contact list only shows one phone number using intent ContactsContract

Tags: android, android-contacts, phone-number

I am trying to get phone numbers from contact list. 
I am globally able to do it, but I have a problem for contacts having multiple phone numbers.

Here is my problem:

- On the AVD (API21), the contact list shows well the 2 phones of my contact

[image]

- On my real phone (android 5.0.2 => API21), it only shows the first phone. Not all of them, as it is on the AVD.

Do you know why the behavior is different between the AVD and my real phone ?

Here is how I'm calling the intent:

```
    Intent contactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,  ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);                           
    contactIntent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
    startActivityForResult(contactIntent, PICK_CONTACT);
```

Here is my OnActivity code:

```
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);


    //Field to fill with the selected phone number
    final EditText textPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Phone);

    if (data != null) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();

        if (uri != null){

            //Get the phone number id from the Uri
            String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();

            //Query the phone numbers for the selected phone number id
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID + "=?",
                    new String[]{id}, null);

            int phoneIdx = c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

            // get the only phone number
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                textPhone.setText(c.getString(phoneIdx));
            } else {
                //no result
                Toast noResultFound = Toast.makeText(SendLocationInfoActivity.this, "No phone number found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                noResultFound.show();
            }
            c.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please does not propose as a workaround to display the contact list, and show a dialog list when I click on a contact having multiple phones.
I tried it, it works, but with this method, the contact list also shows all contacts WITHOUT phone numbers.

Comment: That means, the contacts are showing in AVD but not in device. Am I right?

Comment: Actually AVD shows contact + ALL phones, and real device shows contact + first phone only.

Answer (score 0):

By using ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, the user is presented with a list of contacts, with one entry per phone number. The selected contact is guaranteed to have a name and phone number.

```
//Result code for contact picker
private static final int CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT = 1001;                

Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);
```

If you want all your contacts regardless of whether they have a phone number then replace `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI` with `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI`.

This should fix your issues.